# Is the transfer homomorphism in cohomology surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles

Let $p:\widetilde{X} \to X$ be an $n$-sheeted covering space. Consider a singular simplex $c:\triangle^k \to X$, because the simplex is simply-connected, there exist $n$ different lifts $\widetilde{c}$ of $c$ to $\widetilde{X}$.

Transfer Map: We define the transfer map
$$
\begin{array}{rccl}
\tau_k:   &   C_k(X)  &   \longrightarrow &   C_k(\widetilde{X})\\
        &   c       &   \mapsto         &   \displaystyle \sum_{\widetilde{c} \,\mbox{lift of c}} \widetilde{c}.
\end{array}
$$

By dualizing, we get an induced map on cochain complexes
$$
\begin{array}{rccl}
\tau^k:   &   C^k(\widetilde{X})  &   \longrightarrow &   C^k(X)\\
        &   \phi           &   \mapsto         &   \displaystyle \sum_{\widetilde{c} \,\mbox{lift of c}} \phi(\widetilde{c}).
\end{array}
$$

Since $\tau^k$ is a chain map, we get the induced map
$$
\begin{array}{rccl}
\tau^*: &   H^k(\widetilde{X})  &   \longrightarrow &   H^k(X)\\
        &   [\phi]        &   \mapsto         &   [\tau^k (\phi)] = [\phi \circ \tau_k]
\end{array}
$$
for any coefficient group $G$.

Now suppose that we have a $2$-sheeted covering space. And I want to know if $\tau^*$ is surjective, then I did this:

Let $[\psi] \in H^k(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. We want to see that exists $[\phi] \in H^j(\widetilde{X};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ such that $[\psi] = [\phi \circ \tau_k]$. Let's see at cochains level:

Choose a representative  $\psi:C_k(X;\mathbb{Z}_2) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Given a cochain $c \in C_k(\widetilde{X};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ we get a cochain $p \circ c \in C_k(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Then define $\phi: C_k(\widetilde{X};\mathbb{Z}_2)  \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ by $c \mapsto \psi(p \circ c)$.

Then $\tau^*$ is...surjective? It is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:\tilde X\rightarrow X$ be the projection of a $n$-covering map, $\tau^*\circ p^*$ is the multiplication by $n$. So the surjectivity of $\tau^*$ it depends of the characteristic of the coefficients. If the characteristic of the coefficient is relatively prime with $n$ it is surjective